# C++ giving arrays to functions and returning them

Tags: c++, arrays, function

i have to make a function that copies a array and returns it.

```
const int HEIGHT = 21;
const int WIDTH = 16;
char field [HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    "###############",
    "#             #", 
    "# ## ### #### #",
    "# ## ### #### #",
    "#             #",
    "# ########  # #",
    "# #         # #",
    "# #  #####  # #",
    "# #  #####  # #",
    "# #         # #",
    "# #         # #",
    "#             #",
    "# ## ######## #",
    "# ## ######## #",
    "# ## ######## #",
    "#             #",
    "# ###     ### #",
    "# ########### #",
    "# ########### #",
    "#             #",
    "###############",
};

char copyArray(char copyField[][1]) { //Copy the array field to newField and return it to main

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        copyField[i][j] = field[i][j];

        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
            copyField[i][j] = field[i][j];
    }
    /* for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        cout << copyField[i] << endl;
    } */
    return copyField[i][j];
}

int main() {
    //char newField[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = copyArray();
    //cout << newField[1][1] << endl;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char copyField[HEIGHT][WIDTH]= copyArray(*copyField[][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My Problems are how can i give the copyArray from the main function to the copyArray function and how do i return it?
the copy part is working fine now, i tested it by declaring the char copyArray[HEIGHT][WIDTH] in the copyArray function print it there.
I know vectors and memcpy are working better and are more easy but i have to use this.

Comment: It's not possible to pass an array by value to a function. Nor is possible to return an array by value from a function.  Of course it is possible to pass a pointer to an array to a function and have that function modify that array, but that is not strictly returning an array from a function. You have to be very careful about use of terminology with this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

This example show clearly how to giving arrays to functions and returning them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double* func(int i, double * mas)
{
  double* mas_new = new double[i];
  for(int z=0; z<i; z++)
        mas_new[z] = sqrt(mas[z]);
  return mas_new;
}

int main()
{
  double mas[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
  double* mas_new;

  for(int z=0; z<4; z++)
        printf("%f ", mas[z]);

  mas_new = func(4, mas);

  for(int z=0; z<4; z++)
        printf("%f ", mas_new[z]);

  delete mas_new;
  return 0;
}
```

There are two ways to give the array to function.

```
void foo (int* arr) {
....
}
```

or

```
void foo (int arr[]) {
.....    
}
```

As well as the second parameter is recommended to pass the array size.

To return an array from a function you should return a pointer to its first element.